# What effect does the state of the Council have on the game?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 1, you get several options regarding the composition of the Citadel Council - you can either save them from a certain doom, or allow them to perish and form a new council (either one of all humans, or one with the existing races still included).  You also get to name an Alliance member to the council.

These didn't have much consequence in Mass Effect 2, but it seems like it may end up being more relevant this go around.  What changes can be seen a result of these choices in Mass Effect 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Mass Effect Wiki

The effect on ME2 was:

> If the original Council died, the new Council will refuse to meet with Shepard. If Anderson is Councilor, the Commander can still be granted Spectre status, but this is played down as being a mostly symbolic gesture. If Udina is Councilor, then Shepard will not be granted Spectre status (this is the default condition for players who do not import a Mass Effect game file into Mass Effect 2).

But by the time ME3 rolls around:

> By 2187 CE, the Council is forced to acknowledge the existence of the Reapers launch a full-scale assault against the galaxy. Though Shepard and Councilor Udina attempt to petition the Council for aid in retaking Earth, each individual species was more concerned with protecting their own borders. Thus, the Commander was forced to help the Council deal with their own problems to gain their support.

So it looks like the plot has been structured in such a way as to gain their support regardless of the past association.

Comment: I saw that but it seemed a bit boilerplate and preliminary to me.  If it's true verbatim, though, it means the particular members of the council have zero effect (i.e., this decision is a wash).  Some corroboration of that would be nice.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the all human council option gets washed somewhere along the way and we end up and the multi-species council no matter what.

Comment: Ooh, that's interesting.  (I'm not playing an imported Renegade so that's news, and convinces me enough to accept this answer.  I'll give it a day or so for anybody else to chime in though.)